# I can't use mouse wheel to click and scroll

Tags: scrolling, mouse-scroll

I can use my mouse wheel to click something (and it's detected) but I can't use it to **click and use my mouse to scroll**. I can't scroll on websites, PDF files, literally nothing. I always have to manually scroll or use scroll bar.

I use dual-boot with win 10 and it's working flawlessly on windows. So this problem isn't hardware related.
[here's screenshot of how should it look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rajj0.png)

I know it's achievable by browser extensions but that's not what im looking for.

EDIT: I use Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: and your release of Ubuntu?

Comment: I don't understand. If your mouse wheel is working, why are you trying to click and scroll? Have you looked at the Universal Access settings panel?

Comment: @heynnema you can click the middle mouse button and then a "dot" appears. While the cursor is above or below the "dot", the page will scroll up or down

Comment: @MaxSilvester Never heard of that. You must have added some software, or gnome-shell extension, or browser extension, to do that, yes?

Comment: @heynnema, they're probably talking about 'autoscrolling' in Firefox. You click the middle mouse button and move the mouse up or down and it scrolls in the direction the mouse moves. At least that's my guess. I have no idea what the rest of their problem is, but that's probably what they're talking about with the 'dot' that appears bit. It's a Firefox thing.

Comment: @heynnema I forgot to add, that this is on windows

Comment: This is a similar question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101867/make-mouse-movements-scroll-when-the-middle-button-is-held-down

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the delay. Yes  @KGIII "You click the middle mouse button and move the mouse up or down and it scrolls in the direction the mouse moves." 

This is exactly what I meant. I simply don't see this feature on linux. I use Ubuntu 20.04. Is this only Windows thing?

Comment: Oh, apparently auto scroll is only Windows thing :(

Well thank you all for anwers. Maybe one day this feature will be available on all Unix systems

Comment: The autoscroll feature exists in Linux Firefox. However, you say that this is on Windows? Windows is really, really off-topic for this site.

Comment: unfortunately Ubuntu doesn't have autoscroll  like Windows for **everything**. Including files, browsers, IDE and etc. Autoscroll in Firefox (or any other browser) is only limited to browser.

Comment: And what's wrong with Windows? I just mentioned it because autoscroll is appearing here and not on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You go to the firefox preferences menu, scroll to the bottom to the "browsing" section, then click the "use autoscrolling" box

Comment: Yes, it's working on firefox but this is only a temporary fix. I would like it to work in documents, text editors and other everything where you can scroll. Now I know unfortunetely linux is unable to achieve that... Instead of autoscroll feature Linux uses mouse button to paste previously copied text. Thanks for trying to help.